# How to fix "'X' object has no attribute 'y'"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm coding Brick Breaker and I set up a class for bricks and I'm attempting to set up a collision box for each of them. however, the parameters aren't being recognized for later use.

I'm using Turtle and I'm fairly new to Python. I set up a class for bricks and I'm attempting to set up a collision box for each of them. I did so by setting up a perimeter that is dependant on the brick's position, so I set up a self.colisX variable for each side of the collision box. However, Atom is returning an error saying "AttributeError: 'Brick' object has no attribute 'colisL'."

**My Brick class:**

```
class Brick:
  def __init__(self, color, x, y):
    self = turtle.Turtle()
    self.speed(0)
    self.shape("square")
    self.color(color)
    self.penup()
    self.goto(x, y)
    self.shapesize(2.45, 2.45)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.colisL = x - 25
    self.colisR = x + 25
    self.colisU = y + 25
    self.colisD = y - 25


brick1 = Brick("purple", -175, 275)
```

**in my while loop:**

```
if (ball.xcor() > brick1.colisL) and (ball.xcor() < brick1.colisR) and (ball.ycor() > brick1.colisD) and (ball.ycor() < brick1.colisU):
```

I expect the if statement to register as true but the "AttributeError: 'Brick' object has no attribute 'colisL'" keeps popping up as if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add some more code? Preferably to get a [MCVE].

Comment: Probably the error results from your first line in init. Did you want to write something like self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()?

Comment: `self = turtle.Turtle()`. Are you trying to make a child class of Turtle here?

Comment: To have `Brick` inherit from `Turtle`, use `class Brick(Turtle)`, not `self = turtle.Turtle()`. Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you tried to make a `Brick` class which uses the `Turtle` operations, but overriding `self` does not do what you think it does.

The proper answer is to use [inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp) in this case. However, if you are new to Python, an easier way is just to set a variable to contain the turtle object, for example:

```
class Brick:
  def __init__(self, color, x, y):
    self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    self.turtle.speed(0)
    self.turtle.shape("square")
    self.turtle.color(color)
    self.turtle.penup()
    self.turtle.goto(x, y)
    self.turtle.shapesize(2.45, 2.45)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.colisL = x - 25
    self.colisR = x + 25
    self.colisU = y + 25
    self.colisD = y - 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* subclass `Turtle` to specialize your objects:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
BRICK_SIZE = 50
BALL_SIZE = CURSOR_SIZE

class Brick(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.shape('square')
        self.shapesize(BRICK_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
        self.color(color)

        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)

brick1 = Brick('purple', -175, 275)

ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(-160, 280)

if ball.distance(brick1) < (BALL_SIZE / 2 + BRICK_SIZE / 2):
    print("Collision!")
else:
    print("Missed!")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Also note that `Turtle` has a `distance()` method that makes checking for collisions easier.